# Angular: HttpClient and PHP

Tags: angular, httpclient

Hope you can help me. Just started studying/learning Angular 5. I have a question:
How can i get a response from a PHP File ( ex. querying from DB ) into a Service function and get the response in the Component?

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getQuotes();
  }

  getQuotes() {
    this._data.getQuotes().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getQuotes() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/php/get.php');
  }

}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

// let's say this is a result from a DB query
$quotes = array(
  "Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.",
  "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken",
  "Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe"
);

echo json_encode($quotes);
die();

?>
```

Hoping for your answers. Thank You. :D

Comment: I assume that you know HttpClient.get() returns an Observable? Observable is an object representing result from an asynchronous operation and you call `subscribe()` method to actually retrieve the data from that object asynchronously.

Comment: can you show me an example sir ?

Comment: any one ? :( I still don't get it .